# i want to convert to java 8 stream in this block?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

how to convert to Java 8 stream grammar in this block?

```
List<Product> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
tmpList.add(new Product("prod1", "cat2", "t1", 100.23, 50.23));
tmpList.add(new Product("prod2", "cat1", "t2", 50.23, 50.23));
tmpList.add(new Product("prod1", "cat1", "t3", 200.23, 100.23));
tmpList.add(new Product("prod3", "cat2", "t1", 150.23, 50.23));
tmpList.add(new Product("prod1", "cat2", "t1", 100.23, 10.23));
Map<String, List<Product>> proMap = tmpList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getName));

//start 
List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>(); // 

for(String productName : proMap.keySet()) {
    double totalCostIn = proMap.get(productName).stream().mapToDouble(Product::getCostIn).sum();
    double totalCostOut = proMap.get(productName).stream().mapToDouble(Product::getCostOut).sum();
    productList.add(new Product(productName,totalCostIn,totalCostOut));
}

// how to convert to java 8 stream grammer in this block ?
List<Product> productList = proMap.entrySet().stream()...
```

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question). If you get stuck at a specific issue, you can ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map` and `collect` while streaming

```
List<Product> productList = proMap.keySet().stream()
        .map(productName -> new Product(productName,
                proMap.get(productName).stream().mapToDouble(Product::getCostIn).sum(),
                proMap.get(productName).stream().mapToDouble(Product::getCostOut).sum()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

on the other hand, if you were to lookup costIn/costOut given a product name you could have directly stored the sum of these against a particular product name while `groupingBy`, e.g.

```
Map<String, Double> costIn = tmpList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getName,
                Collectors.summingDouble(Product::getCostIn)));
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You may do it like so,

```
Collection<Product> productsByName = tmpList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getName, 
        Function.identity(), 
        (p1, p2) -> new Product(p1.getName(),
            p1.getCostIn() + p2.getCostIn(), p1.getCostOut() + p2.getCostOut())))
    .values();
```